# show and hide tabs dynamically in touch ui -AEM

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have a requirement, where I need to show few tabs on selection of a value from a drop down.

I have done this in classic UI. But not sure how to proceed for Touch UI. I know that we can use JQuery, Can anyone let me know the approach I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Its fairly simple, look at the OOTB List Component `/libs/foundation/components/list`. The selection dropdown is defined -  `/libs/foundation/components/list/cq:dialog/content/items/column/items/listFrom`, look at property `class` and `cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide-target` these are used to manage hide and show.

Now from here look at the dropdown values under - `/libs/foundation/components/list/cq:dialog/content/items/column/items/listFrom/items` these values trigger the hide and show mapping to property `showhidetargetvalue` as in `/libs/foundation/components/list/cq:dialog/content/items/column/items/setDescendants`

Comment: Its not working for me if it is a tab panel. I need to hide/show specify tab panel up on selecting a value from drop down. I tried to place the properties 'hide list-option-listfrom-showhide-target foundation-layout-util-vmargin' at the tab section

Comment: refer this - http://aempodcast.com/2016/javascript/simple-touch-ui-dialog-extensions-aem/#.WAXG7pN9688

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my approach and the link provided by you helped me